# Flatpak repo objects folder empty?

Tags: linux, flatpak

Yesterday I freed up some disk space (about 1/2 of my disk!) and it seems the /var/lib/flatpak/repo/ojbects folder was deleted. Now whenever I try to update my flatpaks, nothing happens. Here is my terminal output.

```
ID                                          Branch Op Remote  Download
 1. [✗] com.usebottles.bottles.Locale               stable u  flathub < 134.5 kB (partial)
 1. [✗] com.usebottles.bottles.Locale               stable u  flathub < 134.5 kB 1. [✗] com.usebottles.bottles.Locale               stable u  flathub < 134.5 kB (partial) 2. [✗] io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.Locale stable u  flathub < 292.0 kB (partial)
 3. [✗] org.gnome.NetworkDisplays.Locale            stable u  flathub   < 2.3 MB 1. [✗] com.usebottles.bottles.Locale               stable u  flathub < 134.5 kB (partial) 2. [✗] io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.Locale stable u  flathub < 292.0 kB (partial) 3. [✗] org.gnome.NetworkDisplays.Locale            stable u  flathub   < 2.3 MB (partial)
 4. [✗] org.gnome.NetworkDisplays                   stable u  flathub   < 4.9 MB
 5. [✗] io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid        stable u  flathub  < 13.0 MB
 6. [✗] com.usebottles.bottles                      stable u  flathub < 100.9 kB

Warning: While pulling runtime/com.usebottles.bottles.Locale/x86_64/stable from remote flathub: No such metadata object 04dda2e93d1c3a2e41ca49ad86509454d3c8dab30bb8e6147f40a3b045011d27.commit
Warning: While pulling runtime/io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid.Locale/x86_64/stable from remote flathub: No such metadata object 80241ce7552383a9f090c1d0cc77bc6aba037255be37dc805d859bea82160fa5.commit
Warning: While pulling runtime/org.gnome.NetworkDisplays.Locale/x86_64/stable from remote flathub: No such metadata object d94946c0fedf25c811f9b7f93779f292382c89aa231fad90e97faf8dd203a9bc.commit
Error: While pulling app/org.gnome.NetworkDisplays/x86_64/stable from remote flathub: No such metadata object b52da6174c180c1df5b5ab14411a89e771f44a75379a79990a591149537f5b50.commit
Error: While pulling app/io.github.celluloid_player.Celluloid/x86_64/stable from remote flathub: No such metadata object b27881acd04ca55117f614292c30e60e06326ee704a90b753abef4071cb39887.commit
Error: While pulling app/com.usebottles.bottles/x86_64/stable from remote flathub: No such metadata object 4e6ce9e56291193378432b6fb4c5bd7b83de3df7973f8f6cbebc4c1f992bf5c9.commit
Updates complete.
```

Is there any way to re-populate my flatpak repo opbjects folder? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I found the answer: Reinstalling the flatpak does it.